# XML DTD entity validation error

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

In my xml file, I have the following lines for DTD entity validation:

```
<!DOCTYPE production PUBLIC "XXXXX" "abc.dtd" [
<!ENTITY PQ0594 SYSTEM "PQ0594.tif" NDATA tif>
<!ENTITY PQ0590 SYSTEM "PQ0590.tif" NDATA tif>
<!ENTITY PQ1526 SYSTEM "PQ1526.tif" NDATA tif>
<!ENTITY PQ0595 SYSTEM "PQ0595.tif" NDATA tif>]>
```

Then when I went thought the DTD validation module, it is telling me this error:

```
Source failed DTD validation: M/M0099.xml:-1: validity error : ENTITY attribute boardno reference an unknown entity "PQ0594"
```

And another warning later on:

```
ERROR : M0099 : WARNING : Graphic (boardno="PQ0594.png") does not match any entities.
```

What does those warning and error messages mean generally?

Comment: What are you using to validate? Maybe it doesn't support entity declarations in the internal subset? The entity declarations appear to be correct. However your second error appears to be because of the `boardno` referencing `PQ0594.png`. It should be `PQ0594` (based on your entity declarations).

Comment: Can you kindly explain what `<!ENTITY PQ0594 SYSTEM "PQ0594.tif" NDATA tif>` actually mean inside the dtd DOCTYPE string please?

Comment: Those are entity declarations. `PQ0594` is the entity name. `SYSTEM` indicates a system identifier (file on the system). `PQ0594.tif` is the name of the file. `NDATA` means the file is notational data (not XML). `tif` is the notation. See here for more info: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-entity-decl

Comment: If you look in the DTD you should see a NOTATION declaration for `tif`. You'll probably also see that the attribute type for the `boardno` attribute is `ENTITY`.

Comment: I got it, so I think the error is telling me that it can not find the actual tif file while it is going through validation, right?